# TortoiseSVN change automatic merge by extension

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, svn-merge

I'm looking into creating a tool to diff and merge a file in SVN based on its extension. The files in question are YAML-based, but I don't trust TortoiseSVN to merge them properly, since it has no knowledge of the structure of the file.
TortoiseSVN has the custom diff viewer and merge tools in the settings that can be configured by extension, but these don't apply to automatic merges that happen during updates. I know you can edit the config files to specify a diff and merge tool to use for these, but then they are applied to every file, regardless of extension. This also doesn't really work, since the majority of files that will change are not going to be the YAML-based files, but C# source files.

Is there any way to force TSVN to use a specific program for a specific extension, and have that apply to the automatic merges too?

Alternatively, is it possible to call the same internal tool that TSVN uses from my own tool if the file isn't a YAML file?

Thanks